# I'm need to count every word, line , and character of a given string

Tags: visual-c++

as you can see i'm trying to get the word count, character count and line count but the below code is not working.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char ch;
int wc=1, lc=1, cc=0;

    while((ch=cin.get())!='*')
    {
        cc++;
        if(ch==' ')
            {
                wc++;
            }
        else if(ch=='\n')
            {
                wc++;
                lc++;
            }
    }    
cout<<"\n the number of character=="<<cc;
cout<<"\n the number of words=="<<wc;
cout<<"\n the number of lines=="<<lc;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part of the code isn't working? What is the input you're using, what do you expect, and what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I entered your code and compiled it with g++. It is working without any problems. Can you post the error you get or did it compile ?

Maybe your visual c++ compiler is not working right. The code itself should work.

**Edit:** Below a different version of the above code, where no text input is threaded as zero words and EOF is also a break condition of the loop.
EOF depends on your system, on Windows it is Control + z, on Linux it might be Control + d.
The input text might have multiple spaces between words. Punctuation characters and digits (0-9) are threaded as word delimiters as good as possible. Underscore, backticks, tildes and apostrophe like in "don't" are handled as part of a word.
Curly brackets are handled as part of a word to keep the code simple but normal brackets are delimiters.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int ch, wc=0, lc=1, cc=0, old=0;
        cout<<"Enter your text, exit with '*':\n";

        while ((ch=cin.get())!='*' && ch!=EOF)
        {
            cc++;
            if (old<='?' && old!='\'')
                wc += !(ch<='?' && ch!='\'');
            lc += ((old=ch)=='\n');
        }    
        
        cout<<"\nthe number of character=="<<cc
            <<"\nthe number of words=="<<wc
            <<"\nthe number of lines=="<<lc<<"\n";
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know if it works? Is space a character? Why consecutive spaces increment a word count? Can space be adjacent to `\n`, on either side? Do punctuation marks break the word?

Comment: This is a very simple example. Also multiple spaces between words might mess the count up. But basically this is working. When punctuation marks are done properly they should work. I assumed properly formatted texts are passed to the code.

Comment: @areop-enap The code doesn't check for `EOF` so it runs an infinite loop if no `*` character is entered. It miscounts consecutive spaces and empty lines. If you enter nothing but a `*` it counts that as 0 characters but 1 word and 1 line. So I wouldn't say that "*basically this is working*".

Comment: i uninstall my mingw64 and reinstall it and after that it is working don't know whats gone wrong with it but know its working fine..and thank you for the answer

Comment: The line count should be the line count, including empty lines, or do you want the line-numbers of your code files numbered without the empty lines ? And for the words, I assumed the text to be proper formatted. I also assumed this to be a basic code attempt and not to be a perfect lexer. I also think it is not a bug but planned to break at * because how do you enter EOF with your keyboard ? Also, if you have a better idea of this code, why don't you post it ? It compiles, it runs, no segfault nor hangup, it counts properly formatted texts (a text is at least one word), that's it.